# How to print the schema of a dataframe with Python objects rather than Java objects?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For example:

```
df = spark.read.json("path")
print(df.schema)
```

prints:

```
StructType(List(StructField(timestamp,StringType,true)))
```

rather than:

```
StructType([StructField("timestamp",StringType(),True)])
```

This is an issue for me if i want to come up with a schema by initially inferring the schema from a file in order to then print the schema and hardcode it in my code.

Is there a way to print the schema of a dataframe and have it in python syntax so that i can set a hardcoded schema to a variable in my code and use it?

Answer (score 0):

ideally `(schema = df.schema)` works in case of common file formats like csv etc, but for a file like json it's good to provide schema manually to avoid any error